# Matlab - Stratified Sampling of Multidimensional Data

Tags: matlab, sampling

I want to divide a corpus into **training & testing sets** in a stratified fashion.

The observation data points are arranged in a *Matrix* `A` as

```
A=[16,3,0;12,6,4;19,2,1;.........;17,0,2;13,3,2]
```

Each column of the matrix represent a distinct feature.

In Matlab, the `cvpartition(A,'holdout',p)` function requires `A` to be a vector. How can I perform the same action with `A` as a *Matrix* i.e. resulting sets have roughly the same distribution of each feature as in the original corpus.

Comment: Do you mean using either cvpartition(A(:),'holdout',p) which will use all values of A as a vector OR do you mean to apply cvpartition to each row of the matrix seperately?

Comment: No, I don't want the A(:) to be taken as vector as each column here signifies a distinct physical feature. I wish to split the matrix A such that both the resulting partitions(say B1 & B2) have roughly the same distribution of values as it is in A. To further clarify the **distribution of values in column1 of B1** = **distribution of values in column1 of B2** = **distribution of values in column1 of A** and same should hold for coulmn2 & colum3 also

Answer (score 0):

By using a matrix A rather than grouped data, you are making the assumption that a random partition of your data will return a test and train set with the same column distributions.

In general, the assumption you are making in your question is that there is a partition of A such that each of the marginal distributions of A (1 per column) has the same distribution across all three variables. There is no guarantee that this is true. Check whether the columns of your matrix are correlated. If they are not, simply partition on 1 and use the row indices to define a test matrix:

```
cv = cvpartition(A(:, 1), 'holdout', p);
text_mat = A(cv.test, :);
```

If they are correlated, you may need to go back and reconsider what you are trying to do.